# Vue.js not seo friendly

Tags: php, rest, api, vuejs2, rendering

I'm trying to use vue.js. I have these Components named Home where I try to display a list of posts from a WordPress api.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <div v-for='post in posts'>
      {{ post.title.cleared }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Mik Vue.js App',
      posts: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  created: function(){
    this.$http.get('wp/v2/posts?per_page=6').then(response => {
      this.posts=response.data;
      console.log(this.posts);
    }, error => { 
      alert("shit"); 
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

I understand that it works correctly.
But if I look "Page Source" this is the result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VueJS-Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

How can I prerend this list and see it in page source? is there a way to do this without using PHP?
I want also to add meta informations.

thank you

Comment: What this has to do with seo friendliness? You can see js rendered html with the dev tool in browsers

Comment: Homepage is empty if google scrape it.

Comment: O, you should put that in your question too I think.

Comment: Google runs your scripts too, thus will see the rendered content.